# Create table automatically in database backup when I create table from database source

Tags: create-table

I have databases `db1` and `db2` and I want to copy all tables from `db1` to `db2`. I have tried many times. For one table:

```
create table backup.(table_name) select from db1.(table_name);
create table backup.* select from db1.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
select * from db1.database into db2.backup

Comment: ERROR 1327 (42000): Undeclared variable: backup

Comment: Are you using mysql?